# Checking for google play services

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

It drives me crazy how important documentation is often overlooked in the google docs. I would have plucked out my hair if I wasn't bald already.

```
private void checkGooglePlayServices() {
  int errorCode = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
  boolean isErrorResolvable = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isUserResolvableError(errorCode);

  if (isErrorResolvable) {
     GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, errorCode, REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES).show();
  } else {
     if (errorCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        launchApplication();
     }
  }
}
```

The above code displays a Dialog box which says has a button reading ***get google play services***:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES) {

  }
}
```

now what should I do here ? How should I direct the user to the play store to get an update for the playservices? I deem
`getErrorResolutionPendingIntent` to be of use here, but I am not sure how to go about this.

please aid me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code to open Google Play Service Page on App Store:

```
try {
  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_PACKAGE)));
} catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
  startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + GoogleApiAvailability.GOOGLE_PLAY_SERVICES_PACKAGE)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks . This is what was troubling me .

Answer (score 3):

You can check Google Play Service with this:

```
if (checkPlayServices()) {
    // Do your calculation here.
}

private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    GoogleApiAvailability apiAvailability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
    int resultCode = apiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (apiAvailability.isUserResolvableError(resultCode)) {
            apiAvailability.getErrorDialog(this, resultCode, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST)
                    .show();
        } else {
            Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

This will help you to check Google Play Service.

Comment: Thanks. Accept answer, if it is useful.

Comment: This doesn't address my problem . I too have achieved what you have suggested above . I dont know how to open the playstore to the relevant page for the google play services. Right now when I press "Get google play services" , it just invokes my onactivityresult